# C# Identify the different character in comparison of 2 strings

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

`var str1 = "ASD_ZIHJK2A";` \\ Output : pair 1 different character : Z

`var str2 = "ASD_YIHJK2A";`  \\ Output : pair 1 different character: Y

`var str3 = "AWD_PIHJK2A";` \\ Output : pair 2  different character: P

`var str4 = "AWD_IHJK2AQ";`  \\ Output : pair 2  different character: Q

`var str5 = "ASD_RTHJK2A";` \\ Output : pair 3  different character: J

`var str6 = "ASD_RTHIK2A";`  \Output : pair 3  difference : I

what is the simplest way to find the pairs and state difference for each string in the pair using C#?

-the strings to compare is in equal length

-string contain numbers in between as well

-position of the "different character" can different in the second string

Comment: Are you always working with two strings that differ in exactly one character? If not, what are the actual constraints to work with?

Comment: difference in just containing symbols or also order?

Comment: What is the difference (if any) between "ABCD" and "DCBA"? How about "AAAB" and "AABA"? How about "ASD_ZIHJK" and "ASD_ZIHJKASD_YIHJK"?

Comment: To match pairs in a list of strings but the pair of strings will have 1 exact character difference

Comment: So your definition of "difference" in this case is "the single character that is in string one and different on the same position in string two"?

Comment: the "difference" can be in different position in string two

Comment: If the strings are of equal length, then one character being in a different position actually means two characters in a different position. They trade places.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Approach with [`Linq.Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0) which

> produces the set difference of two sequences.
> The set difference of two sets is defined as the members of the first set that don't appear in the second set.

> This method returns those elements in first that don't appear in second. It doesn't return those elements in second that don't appear in first. Only unique elements are returned.

```
var strOne = "ASD_ZIHJK";
var strTwo = "ASD_YIHJK";
var difference_strOne = strOne.Except(strTwo); // Z 
var difference_strTwo = strTwo.Except(strOne); // Y
```

Comment: OP needs to define "different" and you need to explain what `Except()` does. If we reverse one of the strings, the output will remain the same. Is that intended?

Comment: Generally, the OP doesn't know which answer is correct. Otherwise they wouldn't be asking. This answer still fails for "ABBA" vs "ABBB". It corresponds to OP's extremely vague claim "1 exact character difference", yet `Except()` will report none.

Comment: you are correct @CodeCaster "ABBA" vs "ABBB" it should return "A" for the first string and "B" for the second string

Comment: Thanks @fubo but when comes to  "ABBA" vs "ABBB" it it not working

Comment: @newbies please update your question and specify input and expected output

Answer (score -2):

Straightforward  solution

```cs
public static char? FindFirstDifference(string first, string second)
{
    int length = Math.Min(first.Length, second.Length);
    for (int = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (first[i] != second[i])
        {
              return first[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```